# Type Any has no subscript members in invokeAPI

Tags: swift, swift3

I am currently trying to migrate a code to swift 3 and there is only one error left and I do not understand a few things. First things first this is my code:

```
    func getUserId(){

    let param : NSDictionary = ["userdeviceid": deviceid]
    let deviceid :String = (UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString)!
    print(deviceid)
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let client = delegate.client!

   client.invokeAPI("getuser", body: nil, httpMethod: "GET", parameters: param as! [NSObject: NSString], headers: nil) {
        myobject, response, error in

        guard let userID = myobject["UserID"] as? [NSObject: AnyObject] else{

            return

        }
        guard let tokennn = myobject["Token"] as? [NSObject: AnyObject] else{

            return

        }
        self.UserID = userID[0] as! Int
        self.tokenn = tokennn[0] as! NSString
        self.startServiceUpload()

        print("own token:" + self.tokenn)
    }
}
```

I don't really understand the code as I am not the one who made it. I am new into a company and this is the code of the former programmer. I am pretty new at Swift as well and I do not know why this is giving me this error :

> Type 'AnyObject' has no subscript members

I tried to look up the method but i still can't find a thing about it. If anyone knows any alternatives to this I would really appreciate the help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cast `myobject` to a `Dictionary` before using the subscript operator, `let dict = myobject as! [NSObject: AnyObject]`

Comment: ok i did that and now it gives me another error: "Ambiguous reference to member subscript"